# how to upload grib file on postgis

Tags: postgresql, postgis, grib

I'd like to upload grib files on postgis.

I've found [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/49474/importing-grib-grib2-netcdf-to-postgis), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10643161/grib2-to-postgis-raster-anyone-get-this-to-work) and [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25603/grib2-to-raster-grib2-raster2pgsql-postgis-2-0-geoserver) about this topic.

These solutions seem to work only with a grib2 format as the code I tried runs but I had an empty table on my postgis database.

There is a way to upload a grib file on postgis without converting it on a grib2 or a netCDF format?